# Android auto - How to open Google maps with coordinates in Car App?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-auto

*** Solved thanks to Ben's answer****.
I have to change "NAVIGATION"  for "POI" in manifest.

Original question:

I'm working on an "update" of may Android APP to include "Android auto" service for maps. I have tested in DHU and on real device (a car) and everything works fine, but when I wan to launch "google maps" or another "maps app", this code should open it, but it doesn't work. No error but "maps app" doesn't start.

This is the code that I use, into a "onclick element", based on the docs https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#user-interaction

```
     var myCoordinates = latitude + "," + longitude
val intent = Intent(CarContext.ACTION_NAVIGATE,  Uri.parse("geo:" + myCoordinates))
  carContext.startCarApp(intent)
```

)

This is my "manifest" (android auto part)

```
// android auto

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
                android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc"/>
        <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.car.app.minCarApiLevel"
                android:value="1"/>

        <service
                android:name=".programameudisservice"
                android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService" />
                <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.NAVIGATION"/>
```

**** solution *****

```
            </intent-filter>

        </service>
        // android auto
```

Any special element that is mandatory in "manifest" to open it properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide what errors you encountered in your code also?

Comment: That's the problem, no error is shown, it just doesn't open. If I put a "malformed"  uri it shows an error and it crash it, but with the obove one it just doesn't open. Thank you for replying 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most [recently](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/navigation#default-navigation-car-app) used [navigation app](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/navigation#declare-navigation-support) is the one that is used to handle the [`CarContext.ACTION_NAVIGATE` intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/CarContext#ACTION_NAVIGATE()). I haven't tried it myself but I would suspect that, if your app is categorized as a navigation app, it is the one receiving the intent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My app is declared as "NAVIGATION" in manifest (the exact code that you have linked), the intent seems to be "called"  because "function" onNewIntent(intent: Intent) print Log if I declare it, but maps aplication (Google maps) is not opening.....

Comment: That sounds like things are working as intended then. The expectation is that a navigation app would handle navigation intents itself instead of handing off to another app. If your app doesn't include navigation features (e.g. turn-by-turn directions, a map you draw yourself, etc.), you should categorize it as a [point of interest app](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/poi) instead.

Comment: You save my life !!!  thanks a lot... using POI.       <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.POI"/>.   insted of navigate works perfect. Thanks again

Comment: App works fine with POI but was rejected by Google play, because is not App category not permitted...  this have not sense for me.

Comment: Finally using PARKING category was accpeted in Google play